# Understanding .NET Core csproj actions

Tags: .net-core, msbuild

I'm trying to have the contents of a folder copied to build output.  Ideally under the same path relative to the output/publish folder.  I have:

```
<!-- front-end files to serve -->
<ItemGroup>
  <Folder Include="Frontend\Content">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Folder>
</ItemGroup>
```

However, when I use `dotnet publish`, no file is copied.

This works for the config file I want - this was generated by VS:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Remove="my-config.json" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="my-config.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

So my question is - what is this craziness?  Semantically, an element called `None` with a `Remove` attribute - what does that even mean?

My vague intuition is that the element is equivalent to a "set", the contents of which will be actioned based on the name of that element/set, and that Include, Exclude, Remove somehow(?) interact to define and refine the contents of that set.

But then - what's "Folder"?  What's "Content"?  What happens when things double-up: why is the "None/Remove" combo needed?  If it is at all - that was generated by VS!

Documentation-wise, I found:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#how-to-see-the-whole-project-as-msbuild-sees-it, which talks about Compile, EmbeddedResource and None default globs (Include, Exclude and Remove globs).  I know what a glob is, I know what those actions mean, but what are those types of globs?  How do they interact?

It also points to MSBuild documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-project-file-schema-reference?view=vs-2017, but that seems useless for this: it doesn't document `None`, `EmbeddedResource`, or `Compile` elements shown, nor does it talk about the `Content` and `Folder` elements I've found in other examples (and generated by VS).

In fact, nothing I've found yet talks about what this all means.

Where can I find documentation for this?

Comment: There's no craziness. That's how Visual Studio *always* worked. Files whose build action is `Content` get published. Other files are not. If you tried to publish a "classic" ASP.NET web application you'd get the same behaviour. `CopyToOutputDirectory` means just that, that something should be copied to the configuration's output directory (bin/debug or bin/release). It doesn't affect the file's type, build action or whether it should be packaged or published

Comment: You don't need to add `CopyToOutputDirectory` inside a `Content` element to have it published either

Comment: BTW those things are extensively documented since 2002, in the IDE docs, how-to's step-by-step walkthroughs, tutorials, courses. Deploying content like `js` and `css` files is critical to any web application. Check for example [Build Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/build-actions?view=vs-2017)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Are you able to answer any of the questions I posed?  Why my copy task doesn't work?  How the various sets and actions interact?  If the None/Remove is needed?  Where the documentation is?  The link there doesn't cover the vast majority of that?

Comment: (Also - "There's no craziness. That's how Visual Studio always worked" - those aren't mutually exclusive)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sorry - I realise I'm being quite direct.  Please, do you have any of those docs or answers to share?  It also seems like I'm not alone - https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/2642 - which also brings into question, "those things are extensively documented since 2002" ?

Comment: As for the None Remove: the new project files have a bunch of default inclusions, e.g. all .cs files in the project tree get compiled. It looks like .json files are in None by default, so it removes from there and includes in Content. In this specific case, the removal from None may not be strictly required, but consider setting a .cs file to Content - it should no longer be in Compile then.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

1. **Folder items**

`<Folder>` is used inside VS just shows a node in solution explorer, e.g. to get you a point to right click "Add > New …". `wwwroot` is a classic example for ASP.NET Core applications but if you use the VS' "Add > New Folder" feature or delete all of the files in an existing folder, it will add a  node to keep it in the solution explorer.

The `<Folder>` items aren't used during the build. Copying items is determined based on the metadata specified on known item types (None,Content,...) and not based on Folder items in the filesystem hierarchy.

If you want to specify metadata for a whole hierarchy, you could do a

```
<Content Include="my/content/**/*" CopyToPublishDirectory="True" … />
```

2. **Include/Remove combo**

Inside the static content of a project file (not within a `<Target>` - a few different rules apply in there), MSBuild allows three operations on collections of items:

- Include: add an items to the ""collection"" of items of the specified item type
- Update: change the metadata on items of the specified item type
- Remove: remove items from the ""collection""

This means that if you do

```
<None Include="foo.txt" />
<Content Include="foo.txt" />
```

Then there both the `@(None)` and `@(Content)` collections will contain `foo.txt`. This isn't really a problem for the build system (unless you specify you want both of them copied to the output - this leads to errors with conflicting output paths), but for tooling that shows you the files in your project and their properties this can create tricky situations.

If `foo.txt` is listed as `None`, `Content` and `EmbeddedResource`, then the IDE (VS, Rider, VS/Mac, …) tooling has to make a tough decision on what to show you for that file.

To mitigate this problem, it is good to make sure that a file is listed as only one of these "Build Action" item types so that IDEs won't be confused (and transitively also the user).

**So why do have to remove files from `None`?**

The new "SDK-style" projects add a lot of defaults. They basically contain something like (simplified!!):

```
<None Include="**/*" />
```

So if you want to change a file to be an embedded resource or a content item, you should remove the file from the `@(None)` collection.

If you don't need to change the item type, you can also use `Update`:

```
<None Update="some/content/**/*" CopyToOutputDirectory="True" />
```

3. **So what do those things under `<ItemGroup>` do?**

Those definitions do nothing on their own. They just fill / change a collection of "items".
You could even create your own and use them later:

```
<MyCoolFiles Include="cool/files/**/*;other/cool/files/**/*" />
<None Remove="@(MyCoolFiles)" />
<Content Include="@(MyCoolFiles)" CopyToPublishDirectory="True" />

<Target Name="PrintCoolFiles" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
  <Message Importance="high" Text="These are my cool files: @(MyCoolFiles)" />
</Target>
```

The key point is that some parts of the build logic look for items they know a about and use them.

The part that calculates the input to the compiler will look at `Compile` and `EmbeddedResource` items, the part that determines which files to copy to the output directory will look for various items (`None`, `Content`, `EmbeddedResource` and a few others IIRC) with specific metadata set.

New project types may define their own item types to be listed in VS' solution explorer via extensibility points.

But VS will only show items in the solution explorer for item types that are configured in this way. And for these item types it makes sense to not have a file listed in multiple of them.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful indeed.  Could I ask - how/why is `Folder` different from `None` whereby `<CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>` does nothing for `Folder`?  It seems all, or the majority, of other targets support this property consistently.  Do they each duplicate their implementation of this functionality?

Comment: There just isn't any build logic that processes them. For None/Content/EmbeddedResource/BaseApplicationManifest there is the [`AssignTargetPaths` MSBuild target](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/3a844ce00a873d8ca6ba0a8abc0c6b64f772d937/src/Tasks/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets#L2830-L2867) that determines where to copy them, creating some intermediate items, and then [`GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems`](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/3a844ce00a873d8ca6ba0a8abc0c6b64f772d937/src/Tasks/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets#L4437-L4512) uses these to create a final set

Comment: targets such as `_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory` then use these sets to do their work. These targets are dependencies of the [`CopyFilesToOutputDirectory` target](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/3a844ce00a873d8ca6ba0a8abc0c6b64f772d937/src/Tasks/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets#L4179-L4188).

Comment: Whatever you want to be copied in addition to that, you'd need to build additional logic for to integrate into this pipeline.

Comment: For me, this was critical for two reasons: (1) An attribute on a `<Content />` node worked when a `<Content><CopyToOutputDirectory>...` didn't and (2) it helped me realise that some variables that might be defined at the solution level won't necessarily exist, so try not to use them!